# Terraform storage_account_type and size help needed

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to create a vm with following configuration

**Instance series**: F-series

**Instance**: F16, 16 vCPU, 32GB RAM, 256GB temporary storage.

and I don't know what parameters value I need to put in this block of code

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "my_terraform_vm" {
  name                  = "myVM"
  location                 = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.nic.id]
  size                  = "____here___"

  os_disk {
    name                 = "myOsDisk"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "____here___"
  }
}
```

especially for **size** and **storage_account_type**

Comment: The answers you seek are in the docs. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine#storage_account_type

Comment: Well, you have to look at the documentation for starters. For example: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/f-series-vm-size/. You will see that the `size` you are looking for is `"Standard_F16"`.

Comment: this is the error I get 
**Message="Requested operation cannot be performed because the VM size Standard_F16 does not support the storage account type Premium_LRS of disk 'myOsDisk'. Consider updating the VM to a size that supports Premium storage." Target="osDisk.managedDisk.storageAccountType"**

when I put
size = "Standard_F16"
storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"

Comment: You'll have to do more research then.

Comment: A size with `Standard` in its name presumably needs to be used with one of the `Standard` storage account types. You're mixing Standard size with Premium storage.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it and it is

```
 size = "Standard_F16s_v2"
 storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
```